# Internet Explorer 10 gradient issue

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

I have the following button which works in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox:

[image]

The CSS for the above:

```
.button {
    background: linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, #FF7805 10px, #FFA13E 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'RalewayRegular',Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 0.5em 0;
    padding: 0.5em 1.2em 0.5em 0.8em;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Sadly, in IE10 the button actually does something strange:

[image]

Can I adjust the syntax for this to work? I've managed to get a class added to my  tag so I can target it with CSS.

*Fiddle below:*
http://jsfiddle.net/KYmTV/1/

Comment: one tip, that kind of stuff, use an oldfashion image. IE doenst like these kind of things

Comment: You have the wrong numbers for the ms gradient! @DiederikEEn and then you have the problem with not being able to change it easily in non-static designs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the `-ms-` gradient angle:

Going from

```
background: -ms-linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px,  #ff7805 10px,  #ffa13e 100%);
```

To

```
background: -ms-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 10px,  #ff7805 10px,  #ffa13e 100%);
```

Here's your [updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/KYmTV/4/)

Comment: Thanks, glad to have helped.